# Sending system mail via SMTP to public mail server - port already in use

Tags: email, postfix, docker, smtp, mail-forwarding

I have a docker host that runs a containerized mail server.
On the host there are a couple of system status mails in the mail queue that I want to be forwarded to my mail account. These Mails are generated by Debian.

On other systems i have used postfix to do this. On this system however the Mail-Ports are already used by the containerized mail server and i couldn't make postfix not listen on those ports.
The Task itself does not require to listen to any Ports. I just want the Mails to be sent via a public mail account with authentication.

Have i missed a good tool to do this?

Comment: why do you then run postfix on the host, while the same port is already taken on the same host for a other service? That makes for me no sense. Either get rid of the Postfix, as it is not needed or change the port if you still want to use it with a unknown effort. Remind, that it looks for me like a End-User question which will not be on Topic. You can read this [here](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Search using the term: `Postfix relay only server`, and you will find some guidance to get you started. Also keep in mind that Postfix has quite a history and is very old so it might not be container aware/container ready. And I think in a relay only postfix still listens on it default ports, so you might need to reconsider your architecture.

Comment: I made the question more general.
You are right, i don't need to run a full postfix here. I'm about system status Mails by the debian system that i want to forward via a public mail account.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are making sense to me. So: stop postfix outside your container and send the emails TO the container. Probably you need to use the hostname of the computer running the containers. Not "localhost".

Something like: echo "from host" | mailx -r @<validdomain.com> @<validdomain.com>